# My Simulink simulation doesn't generate a graph

Tags: matlab, simulink

In my [Simulink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Immal.png). I couldn't get any graph after running the simulation. Actually I didn't get any error. What should I do for getting a graph from this Simulink simulation?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to start from scratch. First evaluating if you can see only your input signal on your scope. Then start building the blocks. Your problem could be on your plant, on your scope, or on your input.

Also take a look at [Signal Routing with the From, Goto, and Goto Tag Visibility Blocks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/signal-routing-with-from-goto-and-gototag-visibility-blocks.html). This may be helpful.